# Como ejecutar codigo despues de iniciar sesion en codeigniter4?

Tags: login, sesiones, codeigniter-4

me encuentro con un problema al querer iniciar una sesión en CODEIGNITER4. Al ingresar los datos al formulario si se valida bien pero no se redirecciona a donde debe, solamente aparece el mismo formulario y el usuario validado, ya revisé las rutas y al parecer están bien, también validé el usuario y contraseña, pero no me aparece el textarea para publicar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi formulario: `

````
            ```  <h1>iniciar sesion</h1>       
    <form action="user/login" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="login">Nombre de usuario</label>
            <input type='text' name="login">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
            <input type="password" name="password">   
        </div>  
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Entrar</button> 
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>    
    </form>
````

este es lo que se debe ejecutar:

````
               ``` <?php if(isset(session()->user)){ ?>
    <form action="Post/add" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="content" rows="3" placeholder="Escribe algo"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Publicar</button>
    </form>
    <br>`
````

este es el controlador:

````
         ```namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\UserModel;

class User extends BaseController
{


public function login()
{   
 $model =new UserModel();

 if ($this->request->getMethod()=== 'post' && $this->validate(['login'=>'required', 'password'=>'required']))
 {
     $user = $model->login(['login'=>$this ->request->getPost('login'),
                     'password' => ($this->request->getPost('password'))
  ]);
  if (isset($user))
  {
     session()->set(['user' => $user['id'], 'name' => $user['name']]);
     return redirect()->to(base_url().'/Post');
     
  }
  session()->setFlashdata('login_error', 'los datos ingresados no son correctos.');
 }
 

 
 return redirect ()->to(base_url());
}
````